# Printing information according to value of variable in awk

Tags: awk

I have the following awk file and want to capability of printing some details
when the value of verbiage is 1.  Where shall I set the variable `verbiage = 0`.
As I have done or somewhere else?

```
verbiage = 0

BEGIN { display = 0 }

$0 ~ beg_ere {
   title = gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0)
   subtitle = gensub(beg_ere, "\\3", 1, $0)
   keywords = gensub(beg_ere, "\\4", 1, $0)

   nuk = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",")
   nkw = split(keywords, kaggr, ",")

   if ( verbiage ) {
      print "Title: " title
      print "Subtitle: " subtitle
      print "Keywords: " keywords
      print "uaggr: " praggr(uaggr)
      print "kaggr: " praggr(kaggr)
      print "nuk:" nuk
      print "nkw:" nkw
    }
 }

display { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put this in an awk script:

```
verbiage = 0
```

outside of any curly brackets then awk would interpret it as if you had written:

```
(verbiage = 0) { print }
```

so for **every input line that is read** it'll set `verbiage` to `0` then test the result of that assignment, which is also `0` which means `false` in a conditional context, and if that were `true` (i.e. non-zero, which it is not) then it'd print the current input line. So, no, don't do that.

All scalar variables in awk have the initial value 0-and-null so you don't need to set it to 0 as it's already 0 (and null). You've already been shown in multiple answers how to set awk variables to initial values anyway so it's not clear why you're asking this question. Having said that, maybe something like this is what you're trying to do:

```
BEGIN { verbiage = ( (verbiage == 0) && (verbiage == "") ? 0 : verbiage ) }
```

If a variable is equal to both 0 and the null string then it is unset so in this case we [unnecessarily] set it to 0, otherwise we leave it set to whatever value it already has.

If you prefer not to use a ternary expression that could be written as:

```
BEGIN {
    if ( (verbiage == 0) && (verbiage == "") ) {
        verbiage = 0
    }
}
```

In either case, when you interpret your script using `awk -f script.awk` then `verbiage` will be set to the value `0` after the above code runs, while if you run it as `awk -v verbiage=1 -f script.awk` then `verbiage` will have the value `1`.

Comment: I do not understand the reason for the additional `&& (verbiage == "")`.

Comment: I explained that in my answer - `All scalar variables in awk have the initial value 0-and-null`. As I've mentioned a few times now - please get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn about awk. Trying to learn one question at a time is not useful and you're constantly misunderstanding, or just not understanding, awk fundamentals in your code and questions that are all clearly explained in the introductory sections of that book.